# Java call of .NET

Tags: java, c#, c++, .net, dcom

I try to use a .NET Library in Java. Therefore, I use JNI calls of a C++ project which refers / uses a DLL of the .NET.

[image: call structure]

To use the .NET Library I have several steps in-between. First I use C# project as a ‘wrapper’ instance between the Library and a C++ project. The C# project creates a DLL.

The main wrapper C# class (CSHARPWRAPPERSession) is *[ComVisible(true)]* and has a fixed GUID *[Guid("XXX")]*
Out of this ‘C#’-DLL I create a TLB file.
This tlb file is imported by my C++ project.

```
#import ".\CSHARPWRAPPER.NET.tlb" no_namespace, named_guids
```

When I create an exe out of the C++ project I can use the wrapper perfectly and call the needed .NET library.

Now I try to make a connection between the C++ project an JAVA. Therefore, I use JNI and created DLL out of the C++. 
This leads to the error 0x80040154 – Class not registered.

This error happens, when I try to call *CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CSHARPWRAPPERSession)*

I have registered all used Libraries with regasm and done a gacutil on it.
What am I doing wrong? Any ideas or suggestions?